# Quick way to print the regression line slope of two vectors

Tags: r, function, vector, linear-regression

Lets say I have the following two vectors:

```
years <- seq(1991, 2000, by = 1)
height <- c(30, 34, 40, 45, 66, 70, 81, NA, 90, 110)
```

I now want to perform a simple linear regression:

```
lm(formula = height ~ years)
```

All I need is the slope of my regression line to get a trend-value. 
I there any quick way or a function to give my the regression line slope of two vectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd do:

```
model <- lm(formula = height ~ years)

model$coefficients[2]
```

Output:

```
   years 
8.857353
```

A somewhat less readable way would also be doing directly:

```
lm(formula = height ~ years)$coefficients[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this too:

```
years <- seq(1991, 2000, by = 1)
height <- c(30, 34, 40, 45, 66, 70, 81, NA, 90, 110)
df1<-data.frame(Yr=years,Ht=height)

    lmfun<-function(df,yname,xname){
      f<-as.formula(paste0(yname,"~",xname))
      lm.fit<-do.call("lm",list(data=quote(df),f))
      coef(lm.fit) 
    }
    lmfun(df1,yname="Ht","Yr")[2] #or [1] depending on the need
```

Output:

```
     Yr 
8.857353
```